# How to convert parametric form to a single algebraic equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm pretty sure this is impossible to do but here is my attempt.

Parametric form:

$$x=1+t\\y=2+2t\\z=3+3t$$

Attempt:

$$(x,y,z)=(1+t,2+2t,3+3t)$$

That didn't really get me anywhere, so here I tried to put it into symmetric form:

$$x-1=\frac{y-2}2=\frac{z-3}3$$

Basically, I'm trying to get it into something like this:

$$z^2+xy-2x-y^2=1$$

I am aware that represents a plane but I'm trying to get an equation to represent a line. If this is not possible, what can an equation represent? Only planes? Is there any easy way to tell what an equation represents from just looking at it if it can represent more than one thing?

Also, bonus question:

I am trying to put the equation $z=2$ into a function. Is $F(x,y,z)=z-2$ correct? My graph of F doesn't match z=2: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+F%28x%2Cy%2Cz%29%3Dz-2

Comment: Since y=2x and z=3x this line will cross any plane z=C in one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equation $L=R$ can be rewritten as $L-R=0$. Suppose now that you have equations $L_1=R_1$, $L_2=R_2$, etc. Well, you can rewrite them all and then pull a rabbit out of your hat:
$$(L_1-R_1)^2+(L_2-R_2)^2+\cdots+(L_n-R_n)^2=0.$$
This sort of thing is not done terribly often, I don't think, because it is usually much easier to manipulate a system of simple equations than one somewhat monstrous one, but there are probably some applications for it I don't know about. Note: this technique does not work for complex numbers. It's a totally ordered ring only sort of thing.

Comment: Since $L_n-R_n=0$, can't you raise each term to any exponent, not just 2? Also, does this answer my first question or bonus question because I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how it answers my question.

Comment: @user1251385 This finishes off the "symmetric form" solution you started. I don't understand your "bonus" question.

Comment: For the bonus question, I am trying to do the same thing as done here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540612/how-to-convert-a-3-variable-implicit-equation-into-a-function but instead of $xy+yz+zx=7$, I am trying to do it for $z=2$.

Comment: This is Feynman's $U = 0$ trick!  See his *Lectures on Physics*.

Comment: @RobertLewis, it's even possible I read about it there, but I haven't looked at those books in years, so I don't remember.

Comment: @user1251385, the point of squaring is to ensure every non-zero value gives a positive one. You could take any even positive power you like, but squares are simplest.

Comment: How can you get a non-zero value if $L_1=R_1, L_2=R_2, etc$?

Comment: @user1251385, you can't; that's the point. You get a value of $0$ if and only if the original system of equations is satisfied.

Comment: This trick allowed Jones & all to exhibit a [Diophantine equation in $26$ variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Formula_based_on_a_system_of_Diophantine_equations) verified only for $k+2$ a prime number (and an inequality producing only primes).